# How to access deep nested NSDictionary in Swift 3? previously we used to access like this -

Tags: ios, nested, nsdictionary, swift3, xcode8

```
aryTblContentfromHome[0]["movieList"]!![0]["likesPer"]!!["text"] as?String

aryComments[0]["userName"]!!["text"] as?String
```

Comment: Now it give us an error in Swift3 - Type 'Any?' has no subscript members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider unwrapping it step by step. Doing that you can also make sure that your app does not crash because of force unwrapping if in any case the data is not in the format that you want it to be in. Consider the following code, I tried to safely unwrap depending on your given code.

```
if let dictionaryArray = aryTblContentfromHome[0] as? [String:AnyObject],
    let moviesArray = dictionaryArray["movieList"] as? [[String:AnyObject]],
    let likesDictionary = moviesArray[0]["likesPer"] as? [String:AnyObject],
    let text = likesDictionary["text"] as? String{
    print(text)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help